# Accessing array in private class

Tags: java, arrays, private

I am confused on how to access the array temp in order to compare the current array element temp[i] to max sales which is 0 in order to determine which is bigger,each time i try i cannot access temp IN STEP 8 and STEP 7, i do not want to change the visibility of the classes

```
public class Sales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sales;

        sales = getSales();
        printSales(sales);
        printSummary(sales);
    }

    private static int[] getSales() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] temp;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of salespeople: ");
        temp = new int[input.nextInt()]; // Step 1

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) // Step 2
        {
            System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            temp[i] = input.nextInt(); // Step 3
        }
        return temp; // Step 4
    }

    private static void printSales(int[] s) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Salesperson   Sales");
        System.out.println("-----------   -----");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Step 5
        {
            System.out.printf("%6d%12d\n", i + 1, s[i]); // Step 6
        }
    }

    private static void printSummary(int[] s) {
        int sum = 0;
        int max_sale = 0; // Salesperson with the most sales
        int min_sale = 0; // Salesperson with the least sales

        for (int i = 0; i < ________; i++) // Step 7
        {
            ____________ // Step 8

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total sales:  " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average sales: " + (double) sum / s.length);
        System.out.println("Salesperson " + (max_sale + 1) + " had the maximum sale with " + s[max_sale]);
        System.out.println("Salesperson " + (min_sale + 1) + " had the minimum sale with " + s[min_sale]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get, is it run-time or build-time, and what are you willing to change?

Comment: You need to be more specific. `i cannot access temp` is extremely vague and does not help us when we're trying to answer your question.

Comment: Which temp array you are talking about? I think the way you are doing it looks fine. Can you be more clear?

Comment: May I also suggest better indentation, it would make your code more easily understood.

Comment: I have updated the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp` is a local variable that had been created in the `main` and passed to your `printSummary(int[] s)` method, so there you can access it by using `s`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { // STEP 7
    if (s[i] > max_sale) max_sale = s[i]; // STEP 8
    if (s[i] < min_sale) min_sale = s[i];
    sum += s[i];
}
```

Comment: It produces the right outcome but also                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1535
 at Sales.printSummary(Sales.java:61)
 at Sales.main(Sales.java:11)                                                                     any idea why??

Comment: @Brent, this statement cannot throw any exception, I guarantee it

Comment: @Brent, use `max_sale` instead of `s[max_sale]`

Comment: while it does produce the proper total and average sales, it resorts to an error after, this appears "     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 300
 at Sales.printSummary(Sales.java:59)
 at Sales.main(Sales.java:11)     "

Comment: @Brent, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you're trying to get element which doesn't exist

Comment: @Brent, before addressing to an array element, you have to be sure that this index exists in your array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108319/discussion-between-andrew-tobilko-and-brent).

Answer (score 2):

Took Andrew Tobilko code and changed it to save the index to the person that has highest sale value. Implementing this replacing your loop will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { // STEP 7
    if (s[i] > s[max_sale]) max_sale = i; // STEP 8
    if (s[i] < s[min_sale]) min_sale = i;
    sum += s[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works at step 7/8 thanks to @andrew

```
int max = 0; 
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

for (int i= 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
sum += s[i]; 
if (s[i] > max) { 
max_sale = i; 
max = s[i]; 
} 
if (s[i] < min) { 
min_sale = i; 
min = s[i]; 
} 
}
```